# WPF Custom Components and URIs

Tags: wpf, image, resources, generic.xaml

I have tried every way I can find to make my custom control understand URI packs - both in generic.xaml and code. All examples I find works fine in my user controls, but never in custom controls.

All files are set to `Resource` - except for generic.xaml, if I change that the custom control stops displaying all together.

If I try any kind of pack URI I get errors at compile time. Relative or absolute, doesn't matter. I've tried putting the images in other assemblies as well, but with no luck.

If I try `New Uri("/Images/btnImage.PNG", UriKind.Relative)` it looks for `C:\Images\btnImage.PNG`, which is wrong. I've also tried `Images/btnImage.PNG` or `./Images/btnImage.PNG` but then it looks for `C:\MyProject\bin\Debug\Images\btnImage.PNG`.

The only thing I get to work is an absolutely absolute URI - i.e. `New Uri("C:/MyProject/Images/btnImage.PNG", UriKind.Absolute)`.

1. Do custom controls only understand file system absolute URI's?
2. `If 1 = No Then Return correctAnswer` (please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using pack URIs, but not without hitting a few snags along the way.

Most examples don't bother to mention you can't use the "short version" pack URIs to refer to the current assemply if the projects a class library.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `/Images/btnImage.PNG` that means go back to the root and walk into the directory `Images`.

What you mean should be ether `./Images/btnImage.PNG` or `Images/btnImage.PNG` which means look from this dir in the subdirectory `Images`.

**UPDATE**
The problem seems to be your actual working directory. Your program is executed in `C:\MyProject\bin\Debug` so the relativ path points correctly to `C:\MyProject\bin\Debug\Images\btnImage.PNG`. Try to change the working directory while debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've tried that. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Another great atempt, but no closer. I need to update my question again. Sorry. :)